# Docker building schema in wrong database

Tags: postgresql, docker

Im trying to have docker build a schema in postgres under the data base my_database. Im using a sql file and docker initdb. The issue is docker is creating the tables in the database called postgres. I was wondering how I would be able to get docker to create the tables in a different database.

I have already tried adding \c my_database. 
In case it was reading it as line by line when signing into postgres.
Ive also considered writing a script but feel there is an easier solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Docker.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  webapp:
    build: ./literate-app
    command: nodemon -e vue,js,css start.js
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
        - literate-net

  server:
    build: ./readability-server
    command: nodemon -L --inspect=0.0.0.0:5555 server.js
    networks:
      - literate-net

  redis_db:
    image: redis:alpine
    networks:
      - literate-net

  postgresql:
    image: 'bitnami/postgresql:latest'
    volumes:
      - ./schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql
      - /bitnami
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - literate-net
    environment:
      - POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=my_user
      - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=password123
      - POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=my_database

networks:
  literate-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Ya ive changed things around and used run however it didnt build any tables this time.

Comment: Paste your Docker file and Commands used to run it here

Answer (score 0):

### Using the official Postgres Docker image

Assuming you are using the [official Docker Postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres), you can control the name of the database with the `POSTGRES_DB` environment variable:

```sh
docker run -d -e POSTGRES_DB=my_database -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

Or from a docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=my_database
```

There are more environment variables you can use with this image as described in the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres):

- `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`
- `POSTGRES_USER`
- `POSTGRES_DB`
- `POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS`
- `POSTGRES_INITDB_WALDIR`
- `PGDATA`

### Using Bitnami Postgres Docker image

Using the [bitnami/postgresql](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/postgresql) Docker image, the [documentation](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql) tells us to use the `POSTGRESQL_DATABASE` environment variable:

```sh
docker run -d -e POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=my_database -p 5432:5432 bitnami/postgresql
```

Or from a docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: bitnami/postgresql
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=my_database
```

### Check the available databases:

```sh
psql --host=localhost --port=5432 --username=postgres --command='\list'
```

> ```
>                                   List of databases
>     Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges   
> -------------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
>  my_database | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
>  postgres    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
>  template0   | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
>              |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
>  template1   | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
>              |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
> (4 rows)
> ```

Comment: Thanks though I understand that. Im trying to run it from a yml file so that everything is automated

Comment: Actually I think I can use this to create a docker file. Im still very new to docker. But I think this could work